# Creating a priority queue class in PHP

Tags: php, oop, priority-queue

I am attempting to create a priority queue class with array object in PHP. I know there is the SplPriorityQueue in PHP, but I am trying to practice object oriented programming here. Priority Queues have data and priority level, so I have a rough MyQueue class that implements these attributes. I am not sure if I am going in the right direction here. I have not worked with arrayObject's in PHP before.

```
public class MyQueue{
    private string data;
    private int priority;

    myQueue = arrayObject(array(data => priority));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Priority queue class might look like this:

```
class MyQueue implements Iterator, Countable {
    private $data;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->data = array();
    }

    function compare($priority1, $priority2) {}

    function count() {
        return count($this->data);
    }

    function extract() {
        $result = $this->current();
        $this->next();
        return $result;
    }

    function current() {
        return current($this->data). ' - ' .$this->key();
    }

    function key() {
        return key($this->data);
    }

    function next() {
        return next($this->data);
    }

    function insert($name, $priority) {
        $this->data[$name] = $priority;
        asort($this->data);
        return $this;
    }

    function isEmpty() {
        return empty($this->data);
    }

    function recoverFromCorruption() {}

    function rewind() {}

    function valid() {
        return (null === key($this->data)) ? false : true;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$items = new MyQueue();

$items ->insert('Charles', 8)
       ->insert('James', 1)
       ->insert('Michael', 4)
       ->insert('John', 2)
       ->insert('David', 6)
       ->insert('William', 5)
       ->insert('Robert', 3)
       ->insert('Richard', 7);

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo $item,'<br>';
}
```

Comment: This looks impressive. Why do you use the constructor with $this->data = array()? Won't $this->data contain an empty array?

Comment: No it'll contain nothing. You should initialize this variable, otherwise it causes vulnerability (e.g. non-existing index). Some class methods might not work then.